# Google sheets - How to find rows whose date falls into a range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table that looks like this (its populated via a plugin):

```
bugs:
ID   | created | closed
1      2/3/2021  6/4/2021
```

I want to have another sheet, that extracts how many bugs were open at a given week:

```
bugs by week:
week     |  number of open bugs (needs to be auto-filled)
1/1/2021    3
7/1/2021    6
```

In this example 3 means, that on the 1st week of January there were 3 bugs opened (=created between jan.1 and 7).

How can I accomplish this with a single formula in Google sheets?

This is my best effort, but it just fills out a single row instead all of them:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNT(FILTER(bugs!C:C, bugs!C:C>A2, bugs!C:C<A2+7)))`

Comment: Filter function does not work with arrayformula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=array_constrain(
ArrayFormula(countif(weeknum($C$2:$C$31),E3:E)),
counta(E3:E),1)
```

[image]

My sheet is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EOkBvI4No369LEpIUPH0xDhPgLffrw0ccIRFDK-PXKM/copy

After some thinking I found that it's more complicated. You can count bugs that were open during this week or closed during that week or remained open throughout the week.

Comment: Th issue with week counting is that it gives false results if the bugs span over multiple years I think

Comment: I think this solves the issue: `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN( ArrayFormula(countif(YEAR(J4:J)&weeknum(J4:J, 2),YEAR(A2:A)&weeknum(A2:A, 2))), COUNTA(A2:A), 1)` but its still buggy if a week overlaps a year

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula.
No helper.

```
=INDEX(IF(C2:C="",,COUNTIF(WEEKNUM(C2:C),"="&{WEEKNUM(C3);WEEKNUM(C3:C)})))
```

[image]

OR this (if you want)

```
=INDEX(IF(C2:C="",,COUNTIF(WEEKNUM(C2:C),"="&{WEEKNUM(C3);WEEKNUM(C3:C)})&" in week "&WEEKNUM(C2:C16)))
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand how this is supposed to work :( How can I see how many bugs were e.g. on the week starting on 2020 nov. 23? Also it seems to me that it cannot handle if bugs span over multiple years or bugs filed on weeks that overlap years.